# Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection. VBA module in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a macro that will copy a table and its associated queries for each year's equipment audit. I copied some code that I found on another forum, but I receive the error in the title on one line. I'm not familiar enough with VBA to understand what the problem is, so I'm hoping I can get some help.

This code is supposed to replace the source table on a copied query so that the queries don't have to be remade each year. Here is the code:

```
Sub UpdateQuery(QueryName, CurrentSourceTable, NewSourceTable)

Dim strQryName, strCTbl, strNTbl, strCsql, strNsql As String
Dim defqry As DAO.QueryDef

strQryName = QueryName
strCTbl = CurrentSourceTable
strNTbl = NewSourceTable

Set defqry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQryName)

strCsql = defqry.SQL
strNsql = Replace(strCsql, strCTbl, strNTbl)
defqry.SQL = strNsql
defqry.Close

End Sub
```

The error occurs on the "Set defqry" line. Can anyone tell me what is causing the error?

ETA:

When I try to run the code above, I'm also using the following code to fill in QueryName/CurrentSourceTable/NewSourceTable:

```
Sub Proc1()

Call UpdateQuery(YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor, Building_Audit_2021, Building_Audit_YYYY)

End Sub
```

Again, I did not write this code, I copied code that someone else had written and am attempting to use it for what I need.

Comment: Apparently the `CurrentDb.QueryDefs` do not contain a query named after `strQryName`.

Comment: Why even bother with secondary variables? `CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName)`. Now step debug - is valid data passed via QueryName?

Comment: Why would you need to copy table and queries just because year changes? Something seriously wrong with db structure.

Comment: Each year is a separate equipment audit with close to 20k items that are audited. It already runs slowly enough to sort columns on one year alone, plus I'm trying to create a structure that is dummy proof for anyone unfamiliar with Access. I need to keep the equipment that was found each year in its own separate table, hence the need to copy the table structure and all associated queries.

Comment: With debugging, please keep in mind that I am only familiar with the front end of Access. I have an extremely limited knowledge of VBA, and I can't get the debugger to move past that line.

Comment: What is `YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor`?  If it's the name of the query which you want to revise, make it a string value by enclosing it in quotes: `"YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, HansUp! YYYY_Count_of_items_by_floor is indeed the name of the query, so enclosing it in quotes was all that I needed to do.